# I am trying to fetch from a NodeJS backend to a view in React but it has failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from a NodeJS backend to a React view but I cannot seem to get it to work. I am encountering this error: Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function
at HomeScreen. The App has been functioning perfectly fine until now, how can I solve this?
I have included code snippets down below...

"data.js" is a data file where I am trying to fetch the data from.

```
const data = {
    products: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'MonteCarlo Luxury Watch',
            category: 'Watches',
            image: '/images/image1.jpg',
            price: 120,
            countInStock: 20,
            brand: 'Monte Carlo',
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High end, Top Quality Luxury Watch'
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'MonteBlanc Luxury Watch',
            category: 'Watches',
            image: '/images/image2.jpg',
            price: 300,
            countInStock: 30,
            brand: 'Monte Blanc',
            rating: 4.5,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High end, Top Quality Luxury Watch'
        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            name: 'Rolex Luxury Watch',
            category: 'Watches',
            image: '/images/image3.jpg',
            price: 250,
            countInStock: 0,
            brand: 'Rolex Watch',
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High end, Top Quality Luxury Watch'
        },
        {
            _id: 4,
            name: "Lacoste Women's Luxury Watch",
            category: 'Watches',
            image: '/images/image4.jpg',
            price: 120,
            countInStock: 10,
            brand: 'Lacoste Watch',
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High end, Top Quality Luxury Watch'
        },
        {
            _id: 5,
            name: 'Diamond Luxury Watch',
            category: 'Watches',
            image: '/images/image5.jpg',
            price: 400,
            countInStock: 15,
            brand: 'Diamond Plated',
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High end, Top Quality Luxury Watch'
        },
        {
            _id: 6,
            name: 'Rolex Luxury Watch',
            category: 'Watches',
            image: '/images/image6.jpg',
            price: 120,
            countInStock: 20,
            brand: 'Rolex Watch',
            rating: 4.8,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High end, Top Quality Luxury Watch'
        },
        {
            _id: 7,
            name: 'MonteBlanc Luxury Watch',
            category: 'Watches',
            image: '/images/image7.jpg',
            price: 300,
            countInStock: 5,
            brand: 'Monte Blanc',
            rating: 5,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High end, Top Quality Luxury Watch'
        }
    ]
}

module. Exports = { data };
```

This is my "server.js" file for the backend code so far.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// import data from './data';
const data = require('./data.js');

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    res.send(data);
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is ready');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The Server is running at port ${port}...`)
})
```

The "HomeScreen" seems to generating the error. Data shows in the browser in the browser console but I cannot to seem to get update the React view.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import Product from '../components/Product';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await axios.get('/api/products');
      console.log(data)
      setProducts(data)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="row center">
            {
                products.map(product => (
                    <Product key={product._id} product={product} />
                ))
            }
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

This is the data that I get back....

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data
: 
data
: 
products
: 
Array(7)
0
: 
{_id: 1, name: 'MonteCarlo Luxury Watch', category: 'Watches', image: '/images/image1.jpg', price: 120, …}
1
: 
{_id: 2, name: 'MonteBlanc Luxury Watch', category: 'Watches', image: '/images/image2.jpg', price: 300, …}
2
: 
{_id: 3, name: 'Rolex Luxury Watch', category: 'Watches', image: '/images/image3.jpg', price: 250, …}
3
: 
{_id: 4, name: "Lacoste Women's Luxury Watch", category: 'Watches', image: '/images/image4.jpg', price: 120, …}
4
: 
{_id: 5, name: 'Diamond Luxury Watch', category: 'Watches', image: '/images/image5.jpg', price: 400, …}
5
: 
{_id: 6, name: 'Rolex Luxury Watch', category: 'Watches', image: '/images/image6.jpg', price: 120, …}
6
: 
{_id: 7, name: 'MonteBlanc Luxury Watch', category: 'Watches', image: '/images/image7.jpg', price: 300, …}
length
: 
7
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
headers
: 
AxiosHeaders {access-control-allow-headers: '*', access-control-allow-methods: '*', access-control-allow-origin: '*', content-encoding: 'gzip', content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', …}
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Comment: what is the value of logging `data` ... can you add it ?

Comment: I have included the data that I get back from the console.log();

Comment: hey, did you checked in the data.js file u have a small incorrect syntax its module.exports={data} not module. exports={data}. Notice the extra space is their in-between module & export

Comment: you might want to set data as `setProducts(data.data)` ... It's better to add an image rather the code like above for logs :)

Comment: Removing the extra space does not change anything but thank you...

Comment: @codingbeast did you try as above ? seems like you have data inside data, so `data.data` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying these changes and see if it solves the problem:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
     await axios.get('/api/products')
                .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);//Logs the full response
                console.log(res.data.products); 
                setProducts(res.data.data.products)
                });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [])
```

[Check out my sandbox for better clarification](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-fog-yew68p?file=/src/persons.js)

Comment: It still throws an error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')

Comment: can you share pic of the output

Comment: I have included a snippet down at the bottom of the output as console. logged() in the browser....